# Как сделать письмо, что-бы оно попало в Badmail по определённой причине

Tags: c#, тестирование, smtp

Как сделать письмо, что-бы оно попало в Badmail по определённой причине.

```
Например Badmailed Messages (No Recipients)?
```

C# код использует PerformanceCounter для подсчёта Badmailed писем.
Собственно кусок кода с указанием каунтеров

```
ItemsInRemoteQueue = GetPerformanceValue("SMTP Server", "Remote Queue Length", "_Total"),
ItemsInSmtpQueue = GetPerformanceValue("SMTP NTFS Store Driver", "Messages in the queue directory", "_Total"),
ItemsWithGeneralFailure = GetPerformanceValue("SMTP Server", "Badmailed Messages (General Failure)", "_Total"),
ItemsWithBadPickupFile = GetPerformanceValue("SMTP Server", "Badmailed Messages (Bad Pickup File)", "_Total"),
ItemsWithHopCountExceeded = GetPerformanceValue("SMTP Server", "Badmailed Messages (Hop Count Exceeded)", "_Total"),
ItemsWithNdrOfDsn = GetPerformanceValue("SMTP Server", "Badmailed Messages (NDR of DSN)", "_Total"),
ItemsWithNoRecipients = GetPerformanceValue("SMTP Server", "Badmailed Messages (No Recipients)", "_Total"),
```

QA говорит, что мы не знаем как это протестировать.

Удаляю адрес To с обычного eml и копирую в Pickup фолдер SMTP сервера. Но увеличивается счётчик *Badmailed Messages (Bad Pickup File)*. А нужно как-то влиять на *Badmailed Messages (No Recipients)* и остальные счётчики.

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Скорее всего, вам надо будет собрать письмо, не имеющее получателей, для одного из счётчиков. Обычные клиенты вряд ли такое позволят, остаётся программный хак.